# How to decode UCS-2 encoded XML?

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008

Sql Query is returning following xml -

```
 <Table>
    <date>2014-01-15</date>
    <Life_x0020__x0026__x0020_Zeal>3</Life_x0020__x0026__x0020_Zeal>
    <Total>3</Total>
  </Table>
```

Here Column name in table is `Life & Zeal` but xml is showing `Life_x0020__x0026__x0020_Zeal`.

I refered to MSDN and found that its a UCS-2 encoding. I am reading this xml from `C#` code and I want it to decode back to  `Life & Zeal`.

How to do this?

Note - I am using `Sql Server 2008` and `FOR XML PATH` command to produce this xml

Comment: You seriously have a column in the table design with an ampersand in the name?

Comment: Same thing I said to my manager ;)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with UCS2.

As Kami pointed out, column names with illegal characters (for XML node names) are translated with their Unicode code-point equivalents, so you technically cannot do what you want to do.

I suggest you add an alias in your `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT [Life & Zeal] AS LifeAndZeal
```

to avoid these characters in XML.

Answer (score 1):

In XML it is not possible to have `Space` or `Ampersand` characters in node names.  I expect this is the reason why they are being altered in the output.

It would not be possible to change the code to show these values.  However, you should be able to alter the SQL to rename it in the output.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to change the encoding is when you are reading from the XML file (or stream)

```
using(XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(
                        fileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("UCS-2"))))
{
    while(r.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r.Value);
    }
}
```